# Where to find username and password for google_sql sql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-app-engine

So for google cloud sql apps I need to connect to the database using php using this:

```
mysql_connect
$conn = mysql_connect(":/cloudsql/hello-php:my-cloudsql-instance", "<username>", "<password>");
```

I made an sql database using the sql prompt in the google console. Where do I find my username and password to connect to the sql database?

Comment: If you're writing a new application, you should be using something other than `mysql_query` which is deprecated and being removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is user root with no password.

You can add more users or change the password yourself using the normal [MySQL Commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) using the sql prompt in the console.

You can also install [phpMyAdmin](https://gaeforphp-blog.appspot.com/2013/05/26/setting-up-phpmyadmin-on-app-engine/) on your app and use it to manage the database.

Answer (score -1):

Cloud sql authenticates using oauth not username/password.